# react redux connect in nested components

Tags: reactjs, redux, connect

Unable to get multiple nested components with redux-connect when rendering

I have created drop-down components with redux connect to reuse in my application.

Components created CategoryDropDown ,SubCategoryDropDown, CategoryTypeDropDown

I am nesting the `CategoryDropDown` component into the `SubCategoryDropDown` -Working Correctly

When nesting the `SubCategoryDropDown` in the `CategoryTypeDropDown` Component only the `CategoryDropDown` `connect()` method gets triggered.

// This is the connect method that is used in all the components
//

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(SubCategoryDropDown);
```

Am I using the component and redux-connect correctly when working with nested components?

Can I update a child component from another parent component? I know you can update parent from the child using props but not sure how to do it other way around.

Answer (score 0):

connect function must be exported,
can have syntax like this, there are lots of difrent ways to do so,
so here `SubCategoryDropDown` component can use connected things as props,

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps 
)(SubCategoryDropDown);
```

now i have actions imported, the maped to props,

```
import { addTodo, deleteTodo} from './actionCreators'

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addTodo,
  deleteTodo
}
```

the things present in `state` like `todos` are use as `props` now, inside only `(SubCategoryDropDown)` component,

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ todos: state.todos })
```

as you are nesting `CategoryDropDown`,
you can pass data to child like this,

```
<CategoryDropDown todos=this.props.todos />
```

Comment: Thanks. Like i said the functionality is not the problem as i am binding actioncreators to the component and all seems to work fine when i am using the SubCategoryDropDown component in my container component but as soon as i  place it in the CategoryTypeDropDown it does not function correctly. MY goal is not to send the list through as props but rather let the component handle it. This is working with 2 nested(Category, SubCategory) but  not when nesting the nested component.

Comment: ok you can try sending `callback` and create function in parent send as callback to child, call it from child as it is of parent

Comment: I phrased it wrong. Is it possible to update a component when another component is changed? I need to update another component when the callback is triggered?

Comment: Yes you just need to `setState()` of parent, and as data passed in props no need to worry in child

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely update the store that a child depends on with redux. It's difficult to know exactly what your issue is without any code.